# missing libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll runtime error

Tags: c++, dll, codeblocks

I can compile my program in Code::Blocks 13.12 (MingW (haven't tried other versions)) and run it within the IDE.

However, when I attempt to run the program outside the IDE I get

> libgcc_s_jlj-1.dll missing

Reading around I have tried adding

`-static
-static-libgcc
-static-libstdc++`

to my linker settings (individually and I used the last two together) which doesn't work
If I copy the .dll files to the same folder as the .exe it presents

> libstdc++-6.dll missing

to my attention. If I copy /that/ .dll too the program will run just fine; however, I'm not sure the legality of moving the .dll with my program, and I want distribute my program easily to others so the static option I read about seems preferable.

(side note: I shouldn't have this error so I'm curious as to what I'm doing wrong)